# Set variable to Memory Address in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

How would I convert these lines (originally python-2.7) to Python-3.5:

```
DELETE                           = 0x00010000L
READ_CONTROL                     = 0x00020000L
WRITE_DAC                        = 0x00040000L
WRITE_OWNER                      = 0x00080000L
SYNCHRONIZE                      = 0x00100000L
STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED         = 0x000F0000L
STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ             = READ_CONTROL
STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE            = READ_CONTROL
STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE          = READ_CONTROL
STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL              = 0x001F0000L
SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL              = 0x0000FFFFL
```

These lines just retrun `Syntax error` on python-3.5

Comment: Remove the `L` at the end of the hex literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 no longer has a distinction between a long and regular int.

Just remove the `L` at the end of the hex literals and you are good to go:

```
>>> STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL              = 0x001F0000
>>> STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL 
2031616
>>> hex(STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL )
'0x1f0000'
```

Comment: Ah... Why did they change it?